# Do I have to install the framework to use an application built with the same framework?...and several other questions

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-4.0

I want to ask a group of questions.

I want to develop an application **CRM**, **what is the appropriate technology to build it using .NET**, with a mention of the reason, although I have thought about using WPF, I am confused about whether to use **WPF .net or WPF .net framework**.

Also, I want to make sure there is no difference between **.NET and .NET core**.

Finally, I have read that the .NET framework needs to be installed on the device in order for applications built using the .NET framework to work. Does this also apply to the .NET and other frameworks?

With regard to the first question, the WPF.NET documents recommend using the .NET, but there are websites that advised that I use the .NET framework, which made me confused because WPF is used to build Windows applications only, so what is the difference?
The second question was due to the lack of clarity of the answers
**And thank you all.**

Comment: YES, you need to install the needed SDKs (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) in order to be able to develop and launch your application.
NO, there is no difference between .NET and .NET Core. "Core" was used to differenciate .NET Core and .NET framework, but now there will be no any other .NET framework versions
Regarding this last answer, as .NET Framework is "deprecated", you should use .NET even for WPF, and the documentation tells you so. The difference between Framework and .NET/.NET Core if that .NET/.NET Core is multi platform, and Framework is windows only